# Importhtml data alert on new row updated

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, importhtml

I am fetching data from ndtv profit, I would like to get an alert for any new row updated in the table. I have 'send mail' functions. which the event funtion needs to use to get the data on increase row from importhtml.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

```
var inc1=IoI.getRange(13,9).getValue();----------- Got row count cell
  var inc2=IoI.getRange(14,9).getValue(); 

if(inc1!==inc2)

  {
 IOincincsendMail();
    IoI.getRange("i14").setValue(inc1)
  }
```

Comment: The answer will be better if you describe how the code solves the issue and even better is you include a complete function in order to show how do your script assigns a sheet object to `IoI`.